# How I do an "onload" event in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, events, dom-events, event-binding

I am trying to call a function onload element, like a onload="function()" in Javascript.

So this is the code:

```
<div class="img-circle" [id]="pet.id" (load)="imgLoad( pet.id, pic )"></div>
```

Function is working fine, I try with (click) and works, but I try with (load), (onload), (loaded) and not working.

Comment: Why dont use it  **constructor** or **ngOnInit**  for load ?

Comment: Do you want **autofocus** on div?

Comment: But the this div is inside a ngFor and de values of params get the value when the ngFor load values

Comment: Without autofocus, just div load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my function i trying to aplication a style in this div, the params was to set a background-image: url(base64);

So... I change to this, and works

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + pic + ') '}
```

Event-binding (load,onload,loaded) doesn't exists.

Comment: Good to know that you solved your problem, but ngStyle is different thing. Also more appropiate to use will be ngAfterViewInt()

Answer (score 5):

The proper way of replacing the onload function is by using `ngOnInit`. Just implement `OnInit` on the app component.

More info: https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Comment: I don't think this covers dynamic content, such as `*ngIf` conditionals

Answer (score 1):

Try HostListener.

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
runThisMethod() {
  // your code goes here.
}
```

When mouse is clicked on document, then  run this method.
However for custom div, use directives + HostListener.
For Ex:

```
<app-myComponent appChbgcolor> {{title}} </app-myComponent>
    @Directive({
        selector: '[appChbgcolor]'
    })

    export class ChangeBgColorDirective {
        constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
            this.ChangeBgColor('red');
        }

        ChangeBgColor(color: string) {
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'color', color);
        }

        @HostListener('onload') onClick() {
           window.alert('Host Element Clicked');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I solve my problem with the answer bellow, but thanks for help.